# How to write sql to get all users between 20 and 35 on this date?

Tags: sql

I'm a beginner at SQL query and need help with this simple code. I need to get users between 20 and 35 on January 1, 2015. I'm not sure how to code the date part.

```
select
  *
from
  mytable.device
where
  mytable.birthdate BETWEEN 20 AND 35
```

too all, i need to return all users who will be 20 to 35 years old from the date January 1, 2015 so lets say anyone jan 1 1980 to 1995

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: any in general.

Comment: What format are you using to store dates on this table?  You need to cast the dates you're trying to search between to match that format.

Comment: i dont think its so easy what do you mean by all users between 20 and 25 on thi date??

Comment: Your reply makes no sense to me. Also you say between 20 and 35 in title but 20 to 25 in the question, which one is it and is it their age you are talking about?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry typo.

Comment: Ok but the rest of my questions?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thats is what i asked

Comment: too all, i need to return all users who will be 20 to 35 years old from the date January 1, 2015 so lets say anyone jan 1 1980 to 1995

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd find the difference between the birthdate and Jan 1, 2015, in years, and filter where the difference is between 20 and 35. See my answer for a SQL Server-specific query.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you'd use `DATEDIFF` to find the difference between the birthdate and Jan 1, 2015.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable.device
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(YEAR,mytable.birthdate,'1/1/2015') BETWEEN 20 AND 35
```

Comment: This is the good answer, except that the date format may need changing depending on the database used. It is probably safer to use the ISO standard `2015-1-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: although date arithmetic **is** defined in the SQL standard, only a few DBMS products actually support the ANSI SQL when it comes to date or timestamp arithmetic.

The basic idea is that you need to calculate the difference between the 2015-01-01 and the `birthdate` value in your table and compare that with the age range you want to get.

Postgres supports an `age()` function that comes in handy here:

```
select *
from device
where age(date '2015-01-01', birthdate) between interval '20' year and interval '35' year;
```

For ANSI standard SQL this could be written using the `-` operator:

```
select *
from device
where timestamp '2015-01-01' - birthdate between interval '20' year and interval '35' year;
```

Depending on the actual DBMS you need to check for equivalent functions that can calculate the difference between two dates.